# Swift Function Algorithm

Tags: swift

when I run this method in my project, the "name" variable is empty

Example :

```
import UIKit

class userDetail {
    static var name : String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func OK(sender: UIButton){
        getUserDetail()
        print(userDetail.name)
        // The first click is nil, the second click is print "test". How can I solve this problem?
    } 

    func getUserDetail() {
        userDetail.name = "test"
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate `userDetail`?

Comment: Could you please at least make your code compile?

Comment: @Desdenova I wondered the same thing. `userDetail` is a class not a variable. `name` is a static property of the class.

Comment: write `class` names with capital letter

Comment: var userInfo = userDetail ()
    userInfo.name = "TEST"
 print(userInfo.name!)

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact code?  It worked on the first button press for me printing `Optional("test")`.

Comment: doing the same thing working for me in Xcode 8 and swift 3

Answer (score -2):

You have to instantiate it, as most of the comments suggest.

You need to do:

```
var userInfo = userDetail()
userInfo.name = "Test"
print(userInfo.name!)
```

As others suggested, you need to make class names (userDetail) capital. This is because class names start with class names. (UserDetail)